# Issue deleting files from a NetApp Windows Share

Tags: windows, storage, netapp

At work we have a NetApp Windows Share setup. I browse with Windows Explorer to a folder which contained thousands of text files. I then select multiple files at the same time and delete the files.

The files never disappear from the NetApp Windows Share. If I then attempt to open the file I get a "this file does not exist error message". The same error is displayed if I attempt to delete it once again.

However, if I select a single file then it is successfully deleted.

Has anyone else seen anything like this before with NetApp?

Comment: Not seen this myself, but my first thought trail goes down the route of the SMB cache... What happens if you go back to the folder after 10 seconds?

Comment: If you select multiple files and delete them what happens if you refresh the window screen? Or close it and reopen the share? It's possible that windows just isn't refreshing the change...